# How do I make a boolean variable that is true if it is divisible by any odd number greater than 1 (including possibly itself), and false otherwise?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, boolean, nested-loops

I need to create a boolean variable called hasOddFactor that is true if num is divisible by any odd number greater than 1 (including possibly itself), and false otherwise. The current code that I can only tell if a number is even or odd and I'm confused on how to get it to come up as true and false if the number is divisible by an odd number or not.

Current code:

```
boolean hasOddFactor = false;
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
if(num % 2 == 0 || num % 13 == 0){
        hasOddFactor = true;
    }
    else{
        hasOddFactor = false;
    }
}
```

I just need it to come up as true for the numbers 13, 26, and 27, but false for 16.

Comment: Why ist there %13?

Comment: Why 26 should return true?

Comment: Any number greater than 1 that is not a power of 2 has a odd factor under the current definition.

Comment: @ZahidKhan i assume because 26 has an odd factor of 13.

Comment: @QBrute yeah, I need 26 to return true because of the odd factor of 13 like you said.

Comment: @WeijunZhou You are correct about the definition, but 26 wasn't returning as true because it is even, but has an odd factor of 13. I'm trying to figure out if the number can be divided by and odd number or not.

Comment: As I said. Every number greater than 1 that is not a power of 2 has an odd factor, so you can just check that instead. 26 of course should return true because it is indeed greater than 1 and is not a power of 2. There is no contradiction.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Oh, I understand now. I misinterpreted what you previously said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
boolean hasOddFactor = false;
for (int i = 3; i <= num; i += 2) {   
if (num % i == 0) {
    hasOddFactor = true;
    break;  
} }
```

Comment: why not just return true?

Comment: OK... and your point is? boolean b = decideOddFactor(params);

Comment: I still don't understand why i = 3 is the number needed, but the code did help me with the answer. How come that was the number that worked?

Comment: @Sheebs: I took the consideration of your question stating that "if num is divisible by any odd number greater than 1"